# i am making a load system for my python 3.4.3 game which should get information from a txt file and output them but it does not work

Tags: python-3.x

this is my code for the load system the problem i have is with the reading part

```
if line:username, password, points, dmgs, chugs, shields = line.split(",")  
  global username
    global password
    with open("Login " + username + ".txt", "r") as f:
        users = {}
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                username, password, points, dmgs, chugs, shields = line.split(",")
                print(dmgs)
```

this is what the file looks like

```
user, name, 0, 3, 3, 3
```

**these numbers are to show variables (points, dmgs, chugs, shields)**
i tried running it and it did not display 3 which it should be (user, name, 0, 3, 3, 3) the 1st 3 is the dmgs variable but it is either make it show nothing or the int is blank and if i refrence this anywhere else in my code it tells me that dmgs is not defined(this is part of a function) this has realy confused me and some people but this is in **python 3.4.3** just to be clear (the function is refrenced after this code and username is defined it is just the part were it needs to print the variable)

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the solution you have written which produces your problem. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused. The code you gave in the question works correctly but you could make the code cleaner.

```py
lines = []
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        lines.append({
                key: value for key, value in zip(
                    ["username", "password", "points", "dmgs", "chugs", "shields"],
                    line.strip().split(","))
            })
```

This ends up with `lines` being a list that contains a dictionary with the keys being  `["username", "password", "points", "dmgs", "chugs", "shields"]`
If `file.txt` contains `user, name, 0, 3, 3, 3` then lines would be `[{'username': 'user', 'password': ' name', 'points': ' 0', 'dmgs': ' 3', 'chugs': ' 3', 'shields': ' 3'}]`

Comment: This is puzzling though I’m not sure because the first code (the one I sent) just didn’t want to work as it was more of a logic error than another error where it is supposed to print the dmgs or any other value from the file and once I have the opportunity I will try the code you have provided though I’m not quite sure how to use it

Comment: I have tried this code I can either not wrap my head around it or i just does not work it gives me the same result were all the variables are either blank or the code is not reading the file

Comment: I'm a little late but could you provide more information?